# Why is mysql running with --skip-networking?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-12.04

I have ubuntu 12.04, mysql version 5.5.35. The /etc/mysql/my.cnf file has no --skip-networking or --skip-grant-tables attributes. It is annotated with the following line:

```
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address            = localhost
```

However when I do "ps aux | grep mysql" the following comes back:

```
root     28880  0.0  0.0  60068  1904 ?        S    Jun02   0:00 sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking
mysql    28881  0.0  1.1 615828 43844 ?        Sl   Jun02   3:35 /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking
```

Why is it running with those attributes?
Can I still connect with JDBC from localhost if those attributes are on?
How do I turn them off?

Comment: How did you start mysql? Did you check the init script why it adds those options? And to your original question ("may i connect?") - have you tried it?

Comment: This should be moved to serverfault.

Comment: I cannot connect, I have tried it with code that worked on a different computer. I started it with "service mysql start"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mysql server was not running correctly. I had to kill the process manually and start it back up using "sudo service mysql start". Now it is running on the correct port and without --skip-networking and --skip-grant-tables.